# How to copy files from a list with a one line TCL command?

Tags: tcl

I have a list of file paths under a variable that I want to copy over to another directory. I do not what to use a while loop or for loop to push the files over to the other directory. What command line can I use to do this?

```
set list_files {some_directory/here1.txt some_directory/here2.txt some_directory/here3.txt}
set other_directory "/new_directory"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is where you want to use expansion and `file copy`:

```
file copy {*}$list_files $other_directory
```